# Copying files from Unix to Windows based on parameter

Tags: powershell, unix, parameters, file-transfer

I run some control-m jobs which generate files and places in UNIX box under various folders.

These files need to be sent to different users who don't have access to the system.

Each time, I have to copy these files from the Unix folder (based on which control-m job was run) to my local directory and then send those to the users.

I am looking for a way to automate this. I want to create an interface where users can specify parameters (Job names), which in turn will copy the file from the particular folder on Unix to a location user has to access to.

The way I think I might have to approach this problem is -

- Share a directory on any Windows virtual machine which everyone has access to. (This will be my landing zone)
- Create a script which transfers files from various folders on Unix to Windows directory, based on the parameters that are being passed.
- Create an HTA interface where users can specify parameters, which in turn will trigger the script and transfer the file, user is looking for, to windows directory

I am not a programmer but I would like to develop something which will make everyone's life easier.

Could someone please advise if this approach is correct or if this can be achieved in a better way.

Moreover, which language will be a good choice to write this script in. I know a bit of shell scripting and PowerShell. Willing to learn anything else if that solves my problem.

Please advise.

Comment: Hi All, is there a way this can be achieved using Jenkins? We have an instance of Jenkins already running in our environment and going down this way will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

0. Obtain empty Windows server
1. Install chocolatey
2. `cinst winscp` (to copy files)
3. Use https://github.com/tomohulk/WinSCP to automate file copy via posh script. Provide adequate parameters for it.
4. `cinst rundeck --params /Service` to provide graphical interface for users in web
5. Manually create rundeck job and expose parameters for users so they have nice web GUI. You can let users specify folder or let them choose from the list.

Comment: Let me try this approach. Thank you.